# How can I get the delivery details of a email sended by /interaction/v1/events

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, journeybuilder, emailmessage

I'm using the request below to send emails using a journey builder/templates, etc:

```
url = 'https://exacttargetapis.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/events'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'charset' : 'UTF-8',
    'Authorization':  f'Bearer {bearer_token}'
}

body = {
    "ContactKey": f"{variable}",
    "EventDefinitionKey":"APIEvent-...",
    "Data":
    {
        "WY_correo": f"{variable2}",
        "Email": f"{variable3}",
        "Seller": f"{variable4}"           
    }
}
```

When I try to get information like bounce rate, open status, click status, etc. Using this documentation [[page]](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/messageDefinitionSendsDeliveryRecords.html) I'm getting a 404 response every time.

```
EVENT_DEFINITION_KEY = "-----"
JOURNEY_DEFINITION_KEY = "-----"
DATA_CUSTOMER_KEY = "----"
TEMPLATE_CUSTOMER_KEY = "----"
DATA_EXTENSION_KEY = "----"

URL_MKT = "exacttargetapis"

# url= f'https://{URL_MKT}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{DATA_EXTENSION_KEY}'
url= f'https://{URL_MKT}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{EVENT_DEFINITION_KEY}/deliveryRecords/{event_instance_id}'
# url= f'https://{URL_MKT}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{event_instance_id}/deliveryRecords'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'charset' : 'UTF-8',
    'Authorization':  f'Bearer {bearer_token}'
    }

response = rq.request('GET', url = url, headers = headers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "key" using here is the triggered send external key in the triggered send definition/ the Event Definition Key in the transactional journey.

After you determined the correct key, you can try something like this in your Python code:

```
EVENT_DEFINITION_KEY = "Your event definition key"
URL_MKT = "exacttargetapis"

url = f'https://{URL_MKT}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{EVENT_DEFINITION_KEY}/deliveryRecords'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'charset' : 'UTF-8',
    'Authorization':  f'Bearer {bearer_token}'
    }

response = rq.request('GET', url = url, headers = headers)
print(response.content)
```

Regarding information for bounce, open status, click status, etc.. you would want to use SQL with Marketing Cloud [data views](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5) instead.

Comment: I tried, but still having the same results "404 response". I'll read about SQL, thanks for your response!!

Comment: @AlexSoto if you are sure you have the correct key, try to switch to Tenant-Specific Endpoint, I tried that way and it worked while you were using the old legacy endpoint `exacttargetapis`,  Tenant-Specific Endpoint will have a tenant ID as part of the URL, such as this: mc563885gzs27c5t9-63k636ttgm.rest.marketingcloudapis.com [Article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000392227&type=1)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not pursuing this solution anymore. Yesterday, I realized that there is a team that migrates all the necessary information from all the marketing cloud campaigns.

Comment: I tried one last time with another key that I found, and it worked; the only issue was the "event_definition_key".

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned from the beginning of my answer that you need to determine the correct key.